# Largest regular $k$-simplex inscribed in a $d$-cube, $k < d$

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

The largest (by edge length) regular simplex inscribed in a unit cube
is well known in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$:

---

[image]
[image]

 

<sup>Image sources: 
[left: NMSU](https://www.math.nmsu.edu/~breakingaway/Lessons/IT/IT.html),
[right: Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularTetrahedron.html).</sup>

---

A recent *Amer Math Monthly* problem posed by Ionascu & Strong
and solved by Yuri Ionin (Problem 11693, **122**:2, 178-181, 2015),
showed that the largest equilateral triangle inscribed in the unit $d$-cube
has edge length of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}d}$ for $d \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, and
slightly more complex expressions for mod $1$ and $2$
(but still the same $\frac{2}{3}$ dominating fraction).
Ionin proved that a maximal equilateral triangle has all three corners
on edges of the cube, and exactly one triangle corner at a vertex of the cube.

The proof is not straightforward and suggests
that, e.g., finding the largest regular $3$-dimensional tetrahedron
inscribed in a $4$-dimensional unit cube might not be simple.
Although, that the simple $\frac{2}{3}$ fraction emerges through all the
proof complexities gives hope that there might be an analogously
simple characterization in answer to this question:

> ***Q***. What is the largest $k$ simplex inscribed in 
>   a unit $d$-cube, for $k < d$?
>   Is there a characterization of how the tetrahedron corners sit 
>   with respect to the vertices/edges/facets of the $d$-cube?
>   Is there an analogous $d \bmod (k+1)$ splitting of the results?
>   Are there known results for some $(k,d)$ pairs?

---

Incidentally, the "slightly more complex expression"
for $d \equiv 2 \pmod 3$
is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}d + \frac{20}{3} - 4 \sqrt{3}}$,
which for $d=2$, evaluates to $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2} = \sec(15^\circ)$,
in accord with the figure above.

Answer (score 10):

Allow me look at one aspect, or special case, of your question, namely "finding the largest regular 3-dimensional tetrahedron inscribed in a d-dimensional unit cube".

**I. $4$-cube**

I can find the following largest regular $3$-simplex inscribed in a 4-cube. Essentially I used the same methods as described in the paper [*Computing Maximal Copies of Polyhedra Contained in a Polyhedron*, Experimental Mathematics Vol. 24 (2015), Issue 1, pp.98-105](http://www.tandfonline.com/eprint/nUYTtnfukaqmWaKp5AD3/full) or in this MathOverflow answer: [On maximal regular polyhedra inscribed in a regular polyhedron](https://mathoverflow.net/a/154007/39495).
First I solve a quadratically-constrained non-linear program, then I use Newton's method to find high precision solutions, convert them to algebraic solutions using integer relations, and finally check the solutions using calculations in extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since the tetrahedron is 3-dimensional, we can visualize the configuration by taking the intersection of the affine span of the tetrahedron with the cube. This gives combinatorially a prism over a hexagon and looks like this:

[image: 3-simplex in 4-cube]

[Click here for an animation](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/mo/203554/3in4.html)

If the $4$-cube is given as $[0, 1]^4$, then the coordinates of the tetrahedron are
$$ (a, 0, 0, 1) \\
(b, 1, 0, 0) \\
(0, c, 1, 0) \\
(1, d, 1, e) 
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ are some algebraic numbers of degree 8. in fact, we have
$$\begin{align}
a &= \text{ zero near }0.2417346828\text{ of }\\ &128x^8 - 128x^7 + 464x^6 - 296x^5 + 959x^4 - 1568x^3 + 958x^2 - 248x + 23\\
b &= \text{ zero near }0.5021530192\text{ of }\\ &128x^8 - 384x^7 + 208x^6 + 328x^5 - 361x^4 - 16x^3 + 170x^2 - 56x - 1\\
c &= \text{ zero near }0.09686099894\text{ of }\\ &128x^8 - 768x^7 + 2224x^6 - 3848x^5 + 4119x^4 - 2452x^3 + 542x^2 + 60x - 9\\
d &= \text{ zero near }0.6856472601\text{ of }\\ &512x^8 - 3072x^7 + 9408x^6 - 17632x^5 + 19388x^4 - 10480x^3 + 500x^2 + 2000x - 625\\
e &= \text{ zero near }0.8492045976\text{ of }\\ &8x^8 - 16x^7 + 16x^6 - 16x^5 + 6x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 1\\
&\text{and also,}\\
f &= \text{ zero near }1.4379908587\text{ of}\\ &8x^8 - 16x^7 - 28x^6 + 68x^5 - x^4 - 48x^3 + 24x^2 - 16\\
\end{align}.$$

where $f$ is the edge length of this regular tetrahedron.

From the case $(3,4)$, we can observe the following:
In an optimal solution, there might not be a vertex of the simplex coincident with a vertex of the cube (as one might expect from examining the cases $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$)
For the $(3,4)$ configuration, three vertices of the tetrahedron lie on edges of the cube and one on a 2-face.
As you guessed the solution is at least somewhat "not simple": All coordinates of the optimal solution lie in the
number field with defining polynomial $y^8 - 2y^7 + y^6 + 2y^5 - 10y^4 + 6y^3 + 9y^2 - 6y + 1$, which is not Galois.

Curiously, these algebraic numbers satisfy the simple linear relations $a+c+e = b+d,$ as well as $c-d = e-f$.

**Edit**: [Tito Piezas III](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12905/tito-piezas-iii) points out this first set of octics factor over $\sqrt2,$ and that the first relation immediately follows from

$$\begin{align}
a+c+\frac32 e &= 1+e^3\\
b+d+\frac12 e &= 1+e^3
\end{align}$$

which also implies the rather symmetric
$$\qquad\tfrac12(a - 3 b + c - 3 d) = -1+(a - b + c - d)^3$$
The second relation involving the edge length $f$, however, remains enigmatic.

---

**II. $7$-cube**

Next let's look at the case 3-simplex in 7-cube: Here the situation is similar:
If the $7$-cube is given as $[0, 1]^7$, then the coordinates are
$$ (0, 0, 0, a, 1, 1, 1) \\
(b, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) \\
(0, 1, 1, 0, c, 0, 0) \\
(1, 1, 1, d, e, 1, 1) 
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ are some algebraic numbers of degree 8. in fact, we have
$$\begin{align}
a &= \text{ zero near }0.2386303477\text{ of }\\ &x^8 - 12x^7 + 34x^6 - 36x^5 + 57x^4 - 32x^3 - 8x^2 - 64x + 16\\
b &= \text{ zero near }0.7308933837\text{ of }\\ &x^8 + 4x^7 - 42x^6 + 52x^5 - 103x^4 + 384x^3 - 424x^2 + 576x - 320\\
c &= \text{ zero near }0.7613696523\text{ of }\\ &x^8 + 4x^7 - 22x^6 + 28x^5 + 37x^4 - 152x^3 + 164x^2 - 44\\
d &= \text{ zero near }0.8560025785\text{ of }\\ &4x^8 - 20x^6 + 32x^5 - 87x^4 + 16x^3 + 124x^2 - 96x + 20\\
e &= \text{ zero near }0.1439974215\text{ of }\\ &4x^8 - 32x^7 + 92x^6 - 136x^5 + 53x^4 + 188x^3 - 218x^2 + 76x - 7\\
\end{align}$$
The edge length of this regular tetrahedron is the number $f = x\sqrt2 \approx 2.02827238$ where
$$\begin{align} x &= \text{ zero near }1.4342051606\text{ of }\qquad\\ &x^8 + 8x^7 - 14x^6 - 88x^5 - 11x^4 + 160x^3 + 44x^2 - 32x + 68.\qquad
\end{align}$$
Curiously, the algebraic numbers satisfy the relation $a+c = d+e.$

**Edit**: Tito Piezas III also pointed out this is actually $a+c = d+e = 1$, which re-phrases the question as to why their sum is unity.

---

**Edit:**

For all other cases I tried, the following patters seems to emerge: if $s_{(3,d)}$ is the maximal side length of the regular 3-simplex inside the $d$-cube, then we have
$$s^2_{(3, d)}\geq\begin{cases}\frac{2}{3}d &\text{ if }d=0 \pmod{3}\\ \frac{2}{3}d - \frac{13}{24} = \frac{2}{3}(d-1)+\frac{1}{8}&\text{ if }d=1 \pmod{3} \text{ and }d\geq 10\\ \frac{2}{3} d- \frac{5}{6} = \frac{2}{3}(d-2)+\frac{1}{2}&\text{ if }d=2 \pmod{3} \end{cases}$$

- For $d=3n$, coordinates are given by ($n\geq 1$)
  $$
  n\cdot(0,0,0)\\
   n\cdot(0,1,1)\\
   n\cdot (1,0,1)\\
   n\cdot (1,1,0),$$
  where '$n\cdot$' signifies $n$-fold concatenation.
- For $d=3n+1$, coordinates are given by ($n\geq 3$)
  $$
  ( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , \tfrac{1}{4} ) + (n-3)\cdot(0,0,0)\\
  ( 0 , 1 , \tfrac{3}{4}  , 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1) + (n-3)\cdot(0,1,1)\\
  ( 1 , \tfrac{1}{4}, 0, 1    , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0) +(n-3)\cdot(1,0,1)\\
  ( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , \tfrac{3}{4}  , 1 ,)+(n-3)\cdot(1,1,0),$$
  where '$+$' signifies concatenation.
- For $d=3n+2$, coordinates are given by ($n\geq 1$)
  $$
  (0,0,\tfrac{1}{2}, 1, 1) + (n-1)\cdot(0,0,0)\\
   (0,1,1,0,\tfrac{1}{2})+(n-1)\cdot(0,1,1)\\
   (1,\tfrac{1}{2}, 1, 1, 0)+ (n-1)\cdot (1,0,1)\\
   (\tfrac{1}{2},0,0,0,0) +(n-1)\cdot (1,1,0).$$

I conjecture that these values together with the values above for $s_{(3,4)}$ and $s_{(3,7)}$, are indeed the optimal values. It looks like there is again a $d\pmod{3}$ splitting of the result, and not a splitting $d\pmod{4}$, which is what you expected to see. Also the factor $\frac{3}{2}$ stays prominent.

Perhaps this would make a good new question for the Amer Math Monthly, after the case $k=2$ was solved.

Comment: Beautiful! And nice animation. Can you add something about how you found this solution?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke :  Added some more info. some more cases are also probably doable this way.

Comment: Those are compelling conjectures!

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: I know I'm very late for this party, but just an observation: the octics for the 4-cube have a solvable Galois group. (They factor over $\sqrt2$.) However, the octics for the 7-cube are not solvable, having the group S(8). Probably unsolvable for d-cube with $d>4$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: interesting!

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: Ah, so I assume you didn't test if your equations were solvable in radicals? I always do. It does raise the question why one set of octics is solvable, but the other is not. I guess one way is to check the 3-simplex in the $5$-cube. If it still yields octics that are solvable, then it invalidates my theory about $d>4$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I don't remember testing for solvability in radicals.
Unless I'm misunderstanding something: the only cases where octics occur are 4 and 7.
The other cases, e.g. 3-simplex in 5-cube are much simpler, and hence solvalbe in radicals.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Haha great, especially the first one. I think at the time I only checked for integer relations, obviously without looking at the actually numbers in the equality..
I'll edit the post to include your observations

Comment: @MoritzFirsching Do you mind if edit the post a little? I found some simple linear relations including the edge lengths. The edge lengths are $L_1 = \sqrt{s_1}$ and $L_2 = \sqrt{s_2}$, correct?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Please go ahead, edit all you like!
We can also clean up the comments a little after that...

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: I have made the edits. Kindly see if they are agreeable.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, great!

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of results on this (and related questions in [the paper by Hudelson, Klee, and Larman (1996).](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379595005412/1-s2.0-0024379595005412-main.pdf?_tid=23ece39c-e891-11e4-b18d-00000aacb361&acdnat=1429667259_802b1df8453f7d514a3f2b3ef54a5d57) They are concerned primarily with the largest simplex in the cube (without assumption of regularity), but there are a number of results in the paper on when such a simplex is, indeed, regular. The paper also shows many connections  to Hadamard matrices.

Comment: Full reference: Hudelson, Matthew, Victor Klee, and David Larman. "Largest $j$-simplices in $d$-cubes: some relatives of the Hadamard maximum determinant problem." *Linear algebra and its applications*. 241 (1996): 519-598.